# Setting Option+[WIFI ICON MENUBAR CLICK] as default action when clicking the wifi icon in the menu bar

Tags: macos, menu-bar

Clicking on the Wifi icon in the menu bar while pressing and holding the `option` key presents the user with a different and detailed view. The `option`-key is a nice feature. It works on a lot of the menu bar icons as well (sound and bluetooth).

[image]

I'd be nice if I could set this feature as the default action when interacting with those menu bar items.

**How can I set this to be the default action on El Capitan?**

Answer (score 9):

Until now I've only found a workaround:

Install [BetterTouchTool](http://www.bettertouchtool.net/) and create a special trackpad gesture or mouse gesture to invoke an <kbd>option</kbd>+click. In the example below I use the trackpad and a 3 finger double-tap in ***Global*** to do that:

[image]

From now on a 3 finger double-tap on the Wi-Fi menulet (and other menulets) will reveal the advanced or detailed view.

Comment: creative solution though I'd probably want to opt for pressing the keyboard button than install a new software to handle one thing. Regardless, Thanks for your contribution! I may consider it in the end